# What type of attacks can the file be uploaded to the server?

Tags: security

I don’t know if I asked my question correctly, but I wanted to know how it’s done. We have a website, and yesterday we noticed that the index.php file was deleted in the server, and instead added the index.html. We know for sure that the problem is not in the server, I mean that they didn't hack the server, and I would like to know with what attacks they could do this. I understand that there can be a lot of options, but I ask for help, can someone describe how this can be done, or give some kind of link where I could read about it. I apologize if I described the situation poorly, but I think someone will understand what I am asking for, and maybe help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The main attacks are most likely related to a rootkit, specific modification of a server is hard to do with an automated script, so your suspected hacker is likely accessing your server through a back door; you need to make sure that you are only keeping the needed ports open and have firewalls to detect scanners being used on your server. Another option, if you have the funds, is to store your files in a backend storage server, and allowing your frontend server to access those files, it's not foolproof, but it should effectively square the amount of time to detect an open port and pass through the firewall.

Look into these website(s) if you need more info: https://www.veracode.com/security/rootkit
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit

I've proof read these, and they work well for some basic elaboration on the subject, as well as some prevention methods.